# Vue wizard form like wilio

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I want a vuejs wizard form like [wilio wizard form](http://www.ansonika.com/wilio/)

I check the [Binar Code Wizard Form](https://github.com/BinarCode/vue-form-wizard)  But its not exactly what i want.

I want a form wizard with simple progress bar and step number just like wilio.

can we change the Binar Code Wizard Form to be like wilio?

thanks.

Comment: You can use vuetify steppers, https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers to get your this done, it also supports customizations as per your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
Use [Binar Code Wizard Form](https://github.com/BinarCode/vue-form-wizard) and do this Just overwrite this class.

```
.vue-form-wizard.xs .wizard-icon-circle{
   display:none !important;
}
```

And its progress bar will be like this:
[image: progress bar]